# Calling the SonarScanner CLI., Could not find 'java' executable in JAVA_HOME or PATH. for DotNet

Tags: .net, .net-core, sonarqube, sonarscanner, dotnet-tool

I am trying to run sonarqube from docker on linux agent.

1. install dotnet scanner

   dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner --version 5.6.0

dotnet sonarscanner begin and dotnet build commands are running fine.
but for `dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login=$Token` command, it gives error as "

```
**Calling the SonarScanner CLI...
16:09:31   Could not find 'java' executable in JAVA_HOME or PATH.
16:09:32   Process exited with code 1**
```

I tried setting JAVA_HOME also ( with and without bin in path), but it didn't work.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-openjdk
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
echo $PATH


ls -lrt /root/.dotnet/tools/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 142840 Jun 14 11:27 /root/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-sonarscanner
```

I read in posts to change the permission of jre in sonar, but I used "dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner --version 5.6.0" to install sonarscanner, so don't know which location I should go and change the permissions.

Comment: What is your O/S?  That `JAVA_HOME` doesn't look correct.

Comment: OS is linux server -
Description:    Oracle Linux Server release 7.9

Comment: What is in your `/usr/lib/jvm` directory?

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx  jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.x86_64 -> java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.x86_64/jre
lrwxrwxrwx  jre -> /etc/alternatives/jre
lrwxrwxrwx  jre-openjdk -> /etc/alternatives/jre_openjdk
lrwxrwxrwx   jre-1.8.0 -> /etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0
 jre-1.8.0-openjdk -> /etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0_openjdk
drwxr-xr-x  java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.332.b09-1.el7_9.x86_64
java-1.8.0 -> /etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0
java-1.8.0-openjdk -> /etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0_openjdk
java -> /etc/alternatives/java_sdk
java-openjdk -> /etc/alternatives/java_sdk_openjdk
java-1.6.0 -> /etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.6.0

Comment: Can someone plz help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to apt-get install a Java run time/JDK.

referencing

https://community.sonarsource.com/t/net-gitlab-setup/40134/3